# Django deploy Gunicorn and NginX

Tags: django, gunicorn, nginx-config

While trying to finally deploy my NEW rover web app a problem occured. I already configured Gunicorn and bind it to 0.0.0.0:80 (with wsgi). Website loads, but without any images, css, javascript files (even "admin" site is without any style). Postgres is installed and running fine. I already did

```
python manage.py collectstatic
python manage.py migrate
```

I watched tons of tutorials how to do it. But still after I try to run:

```
systemctl status nginx.service
```

i get an error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


#systemctl status nginx.service output:

● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since śro 2018-11-28 02:57:12 CET; 1min 13s ago
  Process: 14721 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 25481 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 25477 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10279 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

nginx[25481]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx[25481]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx[25481]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx[25481]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx[25481]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx[25481]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.




#journalctl -xe output:

sshd[5669]: Received disconnect from 181.15.216.20 port 42140:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
sshd[5669]: Disconnected from 181.15.216.20 port 42140 [preauth]
sudo[5773]: djangosu : TTY=pts/5 ; PWD=/home/djangosu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl restart nginx
sudo[5773]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by djangosu(uid=0)
systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has finished shutting down.
systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
nginx[5957]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx[5957]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address aginx[5957]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sudo[5773]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
sudo[6331]: djangosu : TTY=pts/5 ; PWD=/home/djangosu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
sudo[6331]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by djangosu(uid=0)lready in use)
nginx[5957]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx[5957]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sudo[5773]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
sudo[6331]: djangosu : TTY=pts/5 ; PWD=/home/djangosu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
sudo[6331]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by djangosu(uid=0)
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=djangosu
Group=djangosu
WorkingDirectory=/home/djangosu/website/rover-Project
ExecStart=/home/djangosu/website/rover-env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          rover.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And "rover" file (the same as name of project) in sites-available (I already linked it to sites-enabled):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name :333 ;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/.../website/rover/rover;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

gunicorn.sock exists in /run/ dir.... Any suggestions ?

Release note:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Well, it's telling you that you already have something bound to port 80. Do you? For example, are you also running Apache?

Comment: No. Apache is inactive

Answer (score 0):

nginx is telling you, it cannot bind to port 80 as some other process is already listening on this port. You can see this in your log output here:

> nginx[5957]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

To check which process is listening on this port you could use *netstat* or better *ss*:

```
~# ss -naptu state listening | grep :80
tcp   0      128       0.0.0.0:80                    0.0.0.0:*                   users:(("nginx",pid=6824,fd=4),("nginx",pid=6823,fd=4))
```

```
 ~# netstat -tulpen | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          136280382  6823/nginx: master
```

The last column will show the process name and the pid of the process listening on the port.

Comment: well it doesn't surprise me: tcp    0      128            *:80                         *:*                   users:(("gunicorn",pid=23983,fd=5),("gunicorn",pid=15125,fd=5)). But isn't that something like: request from "guest" -> nginx -> unicorn -> django module -> website generated for "guest". Should I disable gunicorn ... ? It doesn't make any sense...

Comment: gunicorn is supposed to be bound to the socket, not to a port. Are you running it twice?

Comment: Yes you're basically right.
You have the problem, that gunicorn needs to use a different port than your nginx.

I let my gunicorn listen on the internal interface and a specific port with the bind parameter. You can set it in your gunicorn conf or with a command line parameter like "gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8080". You need to change your nginx config to proxy to this adress. I could update my original answer if you need more info on this.

Comment: I think @DanielRoseman is on the better way though - you could check with "ps -ef | grep gunicorn" which gunicorn processes are running.

Comment: My point was the code as posted in the question shows gunicorn binding to a socket anyway; it shouldn't be using a port at all.